# can you set value as thisArg in forEach?

Tags: javascript

I'm learning javascript and wanted to clarify what I read in the docs about setting `thisArg` in a `forEach` function. In my `recycleObject` function, `value` is a new object; I thought I could take advantage of the `thisArg` parameter to access different elements in the array, but I'm getting `Uncaught ReferenceError: value is not defined` even though it is type Object.

```
function recycleObject(date){
    console.log(date) //date is a number like 1999
    recycle.forEach(function(value){ //each element processed in array
        console.log(typeof(value))
        if (this.date==date){return this}
    },value) //this value <--value is not defined
}
```

The Mozilla docs says that `this` can't be set during execution. Is this the problem here and is there a workaround it? Many thanks

> It can't be set by assignment during execution, and it may be different each time the function is called.

Comment: *"I'm getting `Uncaught ReferenceError: value is not defined` even though it is type Object."*  `value` only exists *inside* the callback. You are trying to use it *outside* of the callback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason that you're getting a `ReferenceError` here is that you haven't defined value in the scope in which you're using it. `value` is created within the anonymous function you pass to the `forEach` function, but you're reference it outside that closure, and therefore there's nothing to reference.